# SQL Server bulk insert - "Cannot bulk load. Unknown version of format file"

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Update:** I was using version 12.0.2269.0 of SQL Server but BCP generated a script for version 13. Changing this and got rid of the error but the command is not working anyway. Result is `(0 row(s) affected)`.

I get the following error:

> Msg 4820, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot bulk load. Unknown version of format file "file.fmt".

From this bulk insert command:

```
BULK INSERT Hello
FROM 'C:\data.csv'
WITH (
    FORMATFILE='C:\file.fmt'
)
```

To generate the `.fmt` file I followed this guide:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx

`file.fmt`, empty row at the bottom:

```
13.0
20
1       SQLCHAR             0       11      "\t"     1     person_nr                                  Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     2     fornamn                                    Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     3     efternamn                                  Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     4     adress                                     Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     5     co_adress                                  Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       10      "\t"     6     postnr                                     Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"     7     postadress                                 Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       12      "\t"     8     bevakad                                    ""
9       SQLCHAR             0       41      "\t"     9     limit                                      ""
10      SQLCHAR             0       24      "\t"     10    upplysning_datum                           ""
```

BCP commands to generate format file:

```
bcp [Database].[dbo].[Hello] format nul -T -n -f "C:\file.fmt"

bcp [Database].[dbo].[Hello] format nul -c -f "C:\file.fmt" -T
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Does the `13.0` correspond with your version of Sql Server?

Comment: Weird but no it did not, my version is: 12.0.2269.0

Comment: Have you tried changing the version number in the format file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, se "Update" in post.

Comment: `13.0` is the version number for SQL Server 2016. Have you installed 2016 perhaps? You may have used the 2016 version of `bcp.exe` by mistake

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No only Sql Server express `2014.120.2269.0`. However I have a newer version of Sql Server Management Studio, but I don't think this would affect the outcome?

Comment: I have the same problem, any help?

Comment: If you are only using the file for data transfer in and out of SQL Server, make it easy on yourself and just use a raw file which does not require a format file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#bcp_native_import

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have experienced this.

The simple solution for you is to edit the format file and change 13.0 to 12.0

I ran into this issue when I installed the latest SSMS on my desktop and ran a bcp export script. I got the exact same error as you. My format file had 14.0 and my SQL Server database was 13.0 (2016). Simply editing the version number in the format file resolved the load error for me.

Note: I added the **-V130** argument to my bcp command and I don't have this issue anymore. You may want to add **-V120** to your bcp export.

Comment: Hi Jon, I am adding the -V110 to my bcp command but it always gives me the the 12.0 (which is the bcp version). Can you show me an example?

Here is mine:
bcp [DB].[dbo].[Table1] format nul -f "E:\TMP\DATA\Table1.FMT" -V110 -S MyDbServer -T -c

Answer (score 1):

1. Rename the format file from `.FMT` to `.txt`.
2. Add an empty row at the at the end of the file
3. Change the file extension from `.FMT` to `.txt` in the query and run it:

The format file is basically just a file that pass a few information to SQL, no matter the extension.

I'm still not sure why this always works.

Comment: This was the solution! Thanks! (a single line feed fixed the issue)